# How to build a single .cs file inside the project and get the DLL for that file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to get the DLL file for a single .CS file inside a big project ?

For eg: I have a project named 'Operations' in VS2012 where I have numerous window forms and .CS files.

I need to get a DLL file for the .CS files (which I have changed)... I know we can build the entire project and get the DLL file but how do I get the DLL file for one specific .CS file in that Project ?

Thanks

Comment: A DLL is per project, not file. I suppose you could run the command line compiler (`cs.exe`) and compile a single file, but what benefit would that give you?

Comment: Individual .cs files don't generate their own DLLs.  Are you sure you're talking about a project and not a solution?  If it's a project, you could set all the other files to not build I suppose...

Comment: I have created a custom control.cs file.. where its not getting displayed in the toolbox... so im genreating the DLL file for that and adding it in the tool box.... Is there any better idea to do this ?

Comment: @DanField... The .cs file is inside a project of a solution...

Comment: All .cs files in a project get compiled into a single .dll.  If you want a .dll for a single .cs then move that .cs to its own project.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens... the link says PE (portable executable file ) which gets genrated using the command promt.....but I need the DLL for the .CS files... Is both the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DLL is the output for a library project, and not for a cs file.

If you want to have a dll for the specific class, 
- create a new project with the specific .cs 
- compile it in a new dll file
- add the reference to the new dll file in your main porject

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to move the file into its own project and reference that project when you need to access the class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as long as you have no dependencies on the other files in your project.

You can see different options [How to: Build a Single-File Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-build-a-single-file-assembly)

In short to create a single file dll you can use one of these command lines

```
:: will create File.dll
csc File.cs -t:library
:: will create FileOther.dll
csc File.cs -t:library -out:FileOther.dll
```

One of these to create a single file exe (file must have static main somewhere for an entry point)

```
:: will create File.exe
csc File.cs 
:: will create FileOther.exe
csc -out:FileOther.exe File.cs
```

To create a dll or exe from multiple files you can specify multiple files on the command line: *note that if doing an exe then either: only one should have a static main; OR you need to also use the /main switch*

```
:: will create File.dll
csc File.cs File2.cs -t:library

:: will create File2.dll
csc File2.cs File.cs -t:library

:: will create File.exe
csc File.cs File2.cs
:: will create FileOther.exe
csc -out:FileOther.exe File.cs File2.cs

:: will create FileOther.exe using the entry point from NAMESPACE_WITH_MAIN_TO_USE
csc -out:FileOther.exe File.cs File2.cs /main:NAMESPACE_WITH_MAIN_TO_USE

:: will create alldirectory.exe
csc -out:alldirectory.exe *.cs
```

More general usage for the command line compiler can be found at [Command-line build with csc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)